# Virtual Box hangs when restarting after completing the installation of 12.04?

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Virtual Box 4.3.6 and am installing Ubuntu LTS 12.04.3, on a Windows 8 PC.
I use the default 8GB disk space, and 512MB ram.

However, the VM keeps hanging when I click "Restart Now" after the install completes... I have also lowered/adjusted the CPU execution cap to 50%, but to no avail.

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?

Comment: I had this issue with VB on Ubuntu 12.04 installing Ubuntu 13.10 as a guest, I think this might be an issue with VB 4.3.  If you just close the window(power off the virtual system) it might work fine upon reboot(I think that mine did) or you might want to use VB 4.2  I can't remember if this was one of the issues I had with VB 4.3 that made me revert to 4.2 but there were several so it might have been.

Answer (score 6):

I tried doing the same procedure this evening and ran into the same issue. I fixed it by doing the following:

1. When it hangs, power off the virtual machine (I waited a bit, but I don't think it's necessary).
2. Go into your System Settings, and remove the .iso file from the Storage->Controller settings. I set mine back to Host Drive 'D:'.
3. Start the virtual machine back up. It should now boot into Ubuntu with your configured settings.

I'm using VirtualBox 4.3.6 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Thank you Bill, I thought that I had remembered correctly(but did not want to redownload VB 4.3 and then revert back to 4.2 just to test it).....as I said in my comment above, I think this is an issue with VB 4.3 as in 4.2 this does not happen.  some of the other issues I ran into(if I can remember) were preexisting install(from 4.2)  would not work with the VB add-on pack(for the host), so drag and drop or USB use was impossible...hopefully VB fixes these issues in the next realease...might have to wait until 4.4 as the last time I checked a 4.3 update the issues were still present

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: Please set this as solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it shuts down almost completely, it might want you to press space. Somehow it's not shown.
In this case, the OS has already been installed anyway. Just remove the .iso for the next boot!